# MySQL Dealing with Nested Transactional Stored Procedures [8.0.34]

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, error-handling, deadlock

UPDATE 11.22.2023
Helpful documentation confirming a deadlock always nullifies the entire transaction.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-error-handling.html

Still haven't found a rock-solid approach to handling nested transactions and errors of complex and dynamic stored procedure calls. It's a total mess dealing with MySQL's archaic error handling and transactional system. The only way to do it is with a SAVEPOINT but there's no way to determine if START TRANSACTION has been called (or is active) other than using a session variable -- and if somebody writes code that omits setting that variable, the whole system falls apart. So the core issues are:

1. We cannot determine if a transaction is active/has been started. information_schema.INNODB_TRX isn't even accurate with pending transactions.
2. We cannot determine if savepoints are active.

These two things constitute IMO as a major design flaw in the MySQL architecture, making it nearly impossible to write code that is 100% secure (and not prone to human error of omitting checking and management of session variables).

---

I'm using MySQL 8.0.34.

Here's the scenario.

SP1 can call SP2 which can call SP3.

All 3 Stored Procedures can be called independently, and all 3 SPs process arrays of JSON data and are designed to fail if any one of the indexes fails. As such, each has their own transactional tracking and will rollback the entire process if an error is encountered.

But if an error takes place in SP3, SP1 may want to continue...

I've written a system of session-based variable tracking so (for example) SP3 knows if it's already in an active transaction by checking @active_transaction. If so, it sets a SAVEPOINT and if an error happens in SP3 it does a ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT. If not, it does a START TRANSACTION and sets the global setting.

The real issue is error handling. If SP1, SP2 or SP3 gets a deadlock; the root transaction is cancelled. The problem is if the deadlock occurs in SP3, it's difficult to pass that all the way back to SP1 without SP2 and SP3 having very specific code to "pass it back" even though they can be called independently. I've set a @TRANSACTION_DEADLOCK variable, but using it properly in a cascaded and nested fashion is proving to be a challenge because how does SP2 handle it not knowing if it was called from the outside or internally from another SP?

The other issue is (for example) SP2 can encounter an error before it starts a savepoint or begins a transaction; now I have to track (for each SP) if a savepoint was activated for that stored procedure.

Now multiply this scenario by over 100 stored procedures; all of which inter-mix and can be called either internally (e.g. SP1>SP2>SP3>SP4 or SP3 directly).

I've tried to write a system to track all of this, and it works around 99% of the time, but the 1% failure is a big problem. I was unaware a deadlock (no matter the depth of the SP call) will rollback the entire transaction. So if we're 4 layers deep in a call and a deadlock takes place, that information needs to be passed all the way up to chain -- and the problem is (for example) SP2 calling SP3 may want to handle things differently if it was just an error of type X vs. Y (to determine if it should keep going with the transaction).

So my first question - is there anything other than a DEADLOCK that will automatically rollback a transaction in full (under the hood)? I seem to be encountering transactional resets without any source (making it difficult to handle).

Second - is there a better way to write a system to handle these nested complexities other than trying to track everything in session variables?

Comment: This may be difficult to do in stored procedures, as MySQL's error handling is very limited. Can you do it in the application language? Languages like PHP, Python, and JavaScript have better exception handling with `try` statements.

Comment: Any errors roll back the entire transaction, not just a deadlock.

Comment: @Shadow wait - what? Are you 100% sure? So if SP3 errors out (let's just say some update error like FK constraint missing), the BEGIN TRANSACTION initiated by SP1 is rolled back entirely while I'm erroring out in SP3?

Comment: Yep, that's the default behaviour!

Comment: @Shadow so I just tested it and if the EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION has a rollback to the savepoint defined in that SP, it keeps the transaction open and rolls back to the savepoiont. That's how my system works. So SP1>SP2>SP3 each have their savepoints, and when SP3 has an SQLEXCEPTION it rolls back to the savepoint of SP3 before returning to SP2 - and the transactions prior to SP3 are still intact...

Comment: @Shadow my understanding is the only error that will always roll back the entire transaction (regardless of handling) is a DEADLOCK...

Comment: If you have exception handling in place, then you decide how far you roll back on an error. If an error rolls back only the given sql statement or to a savepoint, then locks are not released, so you may fare worse than rolling back the entire transaction. As Barmar already suggested: mysql's error handling is quite basic. Use application logic to handle complex scenarios.

Comment: @Shadow I have to manage complex error handling given the scenarios presented herein. I'm still very confused about a DEADLOCK. For example, if a DEADLOCK takes place in SP3 and SP3 has EXIT SQLEXCEPTION handler, and rolls back to the savepoint, how come it's resetting the entire transaction? There appears to be under-the-hood behavior by the engine that's not clear. For our system exception handling is just writing out the error and rolling back to a savepoint if it's a nested call... But as mentioned, it's failing 1% of the time, somehow losing the whole transaction.

Comment: If you have a deadlock, then rolling back to a savepoint is not enough as locks are not released. Deadlocks are caused by locks. The only way to release the locks is to roll back the entire transaction as mysql is not aware which statement set a certain lock.

Comment: @Shadow are there any errors other than DEADLOCK that will auto-rollback the entire current session transaction that I may not be aware of?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resignal.html

Comment: Updated the task with additional information on the core issues with this scenario.